# Screen is being displayed to the left of normal position in Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu, and have used xrandr to add 1280x1024 to my secondary monitor. When I do this, Ubuntu displays the secondary screen left of where it is meaning I can only see some of the screen.

Output of xrandr:

```bsh
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   848x480       60.00  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   1280x1024_60.00  59.89* 
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

Output of cvt 1280 1024:

```bsh
# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

I then used the following commands to add the display mode:

```bsh
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

I then opened settings, and selected the resolution.

My displays now look like this:
[displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qCHS.jpg)

I have tried changing the position from my monitor itself, but it isn't enough to put the display to a normal position.

How would I get my display to a normal position?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to fix it on my specific monitor. I went to the settings of the monitor, selected auto adjust, which let me get the screen at the right position then I adjusted the vertical value to set the display in the right place. This still wouldn't work on a monitor without those options.